# Getting the vertex coordinate of a BufferGeometry transformed in vertex shader

Tags: three.js, webgl, particle-system

I implemented a particle system using BufferGeometry and to make things efficient I pass the velocity and acceleration information of each vertex (particle) to the vertex shader and I calculate the position of vertices inside the vertex shader. I need a way to get the world coordinates of a given vertex in the Javasript code but I could not find any except maybe passing FBO from the shader. Is there a better or easier way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Update:

Well, I ended up applying the motion formula of the vertex to the initial position of the vertex and then applying the matrixWorld of the parent mesh to the vector to get the final position. It works but I'm still looking for a better solution.

Comment: What happens in the shaders (generally) stays in the shaders. The exception is if you're using your render target as a means of outputting values, but that would likely be more complex than simply porting your calculation algorithm into JavaScript code and calling it there.

Comment: Porting the calculation algorithm into JavaScript seems like a bad idea because in my case each particle can have different velocity/acceleration and for, lets say 100000 particles, processing these in the CPU is going to drop the FPS. A way to prevent the FPS drop can be the timed-chunks but in that case particles are updated with delay and it kills the smoothness of the animation.

Comment: Have you considered using [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to move the calculations off the main thread? You could use [Transferrable Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable) to pass in a `Float32Array` copy of your vertices (and direction, velocity, acceleration, etc.) into the worker, and get back a `Float32Array` with the updated positions.

Comment: Another option is to wait for WebGL2 Compute Shaders (sorry, no link at the moment), which are pretty much exactly what you are requesting.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Yes the Web Workers might work well (with the method I added to my question, see the update) but it still seems so hard to achieve such simple task. I was looking for a one-liner, THREE.js solution

Comment: in WebGL 2 you can use transform feedback to read out the values. reading it show tho. have you considered either [stateless particles](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/sdk/demos/google/particles/index.html) or like you mentioned , using a texture attached to an fbo. You can use that texture as a source for vertices.